# How to render this angular variable using ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

It's not rendering the actual value for the variable in IE when using just class rather than ng-class. It just shows the variable name for the width.

I'm thinking the syntax needs fixing on my use of ng-class below...

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="jRatingAverage" ng-style="{width: '{{ ReviewRating(reviewObj.Rating) }}px', top: '-20px'}"></div>
```

The value is showing correctly, but it is still showing in the browser as ng-class="..." rather than just class="..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't `{{}}` interpolation directive in `ng-style` directive

```
<div class="jRatingAverage" 
   ng-style="{width: ReviewRating(reviewObj.Rating)+ 'px', top: '-20px'}">
</div>
```

Comment: @Brenton Thornicroft does it helpful to you..?